# DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement Error in Docker but works in Development

Tags: c#

I am getting the DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement when trying to call a public API. Most of the API endpoints are secure but three are publicly available.

These three public APIs are called on the home page before the user logs in and surely this is not a unique situation so there must be a way you can have both in an application.

I am NOT seeing this error in the development environment but I am seeing it when I deploy to my docker container. I understand that DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement is a part of the .NET core Policy-based authorization model.

What I understand [from this article](https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/) is I can specify endpoints to **NOT** apply the DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement. This however is not working for me so either I am doing it wrong or this article doesn't apply to my situation.

Fortunately I am also in control of the API so I can provide the implementation.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MappingController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("businesses")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBusinesses()
    {
        var result = await _mappingService.GetAllBizMapMarkersAsync();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

In the app where I am getting the error I have specified in startup.cs what I thought would be an override for that endpoint based upon [this article.](https://exceptionnotfound.net/an-overview-of-convention-based-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0-mvc/)

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("Mapping", "/businesses").AllowAnonymous();
        });
        
    }
```

The app calls the API like this.

```
var response = await _client.GetAsync($"mapping/businesses");
```

This is the error.

```
[13:39:34 INF] Start processing HTTP request GET https://devapi.mysite.com/mapping/businesses
[13:39:34 INF] Sending HTTP request GET https://devapi.mysite.com:5150/mapping/businesses
[13:39:34 INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.